# How can I keep PII data out of Google Analytics / Universal Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, web-analytics, universal-analytics

I would like to enable the site search report, but I am aware of Google's strict ToS where they request no PII is captured within GA.

If I enable the site search report, and someone types their email address into our site search, does this mean I've violated Google's ToS?

If this isnt considered violating their ToS, please can you post a source?
If this is violating ToS, how can I enable site search without capturing PII?

Comment: This is a pretty comprehensive blog about PII: http://www.clickinsight.ca/about/blog/infringing-google-analytics-pii-terms-service-find-out

Comment: Thanks for the link to the post. it covers a lot of information, but nothing on Site Search (my question).

Comment: Nothing directly related to site search, no, but if it's a huge issue or if you want your analytics data to be PII-proof (not sure why somebody would type in an email address into your site search field), then you could try filtering that data from your reports.

Comment: I actually did have people searching with search terms of email addresses, postal addresses and more! Crazy what people would use site search for!
How can you filter PII captured via site search from GA? Is this post, or pre data processing?